# What do I do when the actual answer to a question is fairly useless in other cases?

Tags: discussion

I have [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299841/makefile-linking-undefined-reference-to-exit) and gotten several responses providing useful information, but the actual answer was to fix a simple error. I could answer myself with the solution I used, but the actual solution was fairly trivial, and I don't want to detract from the other answers, as I could see them being useful for other users. To make things more complicated, the actual solution (which pointed out a trivial error) is in a comment. What should I do?

Comment: Answers that are of the type "oops! I had a typo" or "oops! I forgot to use the variable I defined earlier" (the latter is the case here) are not useful answers and likely to get downvotes.

Comment: I'd leave it the way you have it right now.  It's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flag the question, to close it as off-topic:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

The question will stay around for other users to stumble upon. As you say, *they* might benefit from the answers already given.

Comment: That makes sense, but there is a solution, and the answers provided are on-topic in relation to the error I experienced. I have chosen the solution the explained *why* the error was occurring, even when `_exit()` was defined. I then edited my question to explain my decision.